# Redirect after submit inside php script

Tags: php, javascript, html, header

I know the code is pretty long...but I hope the solution I'm looking for is simple and quick.  So I have a session working here on my order form.  I have two forms echoed depending if the person is logged in.  First if statement is if the user is logged in, it does all that stuff (I know the code is not perfect but it works for me).  The question:
How can I redirect the user to their account after placing the order?  I tried the header function before the }else{...didn't work, took me right to the account page.  I couldn't find the code online because their forms were all inside html, not inside php, so the header didn't work.  Any advice???

```
<?php

    $memberOrder = "";
    $nonmemberOrder = "";

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){

    include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">

    function validate_form ( ) { 
    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
    valid = true;

    if ( document.memberOrder.memberNumber.value == "" ) { 
    alert ( "Membership number must be entered." ); 
    valid = false;
    }
    if ( document.memberOrder.memberNumber.value.match(numbers)){
        valid = true;
    }else{
        alert ( "You must only have numbers entered as Membership Number.");
        valid = false;
    }
    if ( document.memberOrder.payment.value == "" ) { 
    alert ( "You must select a payment method." ); 
    valid = false;
    }
    if ( document.memberOrder.orderLinks.value == "" ) { 
    alert ( "You must insert a link to your order." ); 
    valid = false;
    }
    if ( document.memberOrder.size.value == "" ) { 
    alert ( "Size must not be blank." ); 
    valid = false;
    }
    if ( document.memberOrder.cost.value == "" ) { 
    alert ( "Cost must not be blank." ); 
    valid = false;
    }
    if ( document.memberOrder.cost.value.match(numbers)){
        valid = true;
    }else{
        alert ( "You must only have numbers entered as your item cost.");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (!document.memberOrder.checkbox.checked){
        alert ( "You must agree to terms before placing your order.");
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
    }
    </script>';

    $memberNumber = preg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_POST['memberNumber']);
    $memberNumber = stripslashes($_POST['memberNumber']);
    $size = preg_replace("[^a-zA-Z]", "", $_POST['size']);
    $cost = preg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_POST['cost']);
    $cost = stripslashes($_POST['cost']);
    $cost = strip_tags($cost);
    $color = preg_replace("[^a-zA-Z]", "", $_POST['color']);
    $color = stripslashes($_POST['color']);
    $color = strip_tags($color);
    $payment = $_POST['payment'];
    $orderLinks = $_POST['orderLinks'];

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO memberOrders (memberNumber, orderLinks, cost) VALUES 
                        ('$memberNumber', '$orderLinks', '$cost')") or die (mysql_error());

    $memberOrder = '<form action="order.php" method="post" name="memberOrder" id="memberOrder" onsubmit="return validate_form ( );">
                    <table cellpadding="10" width="500px">
                        <tr>
                            <td><div align="left">Membership Number</div></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="memberNumber" id="memberNumber"  /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><div align="left">Payment Type</div></td>
                            <td><input type="radio" name="payment" value="Bank Transfer" />Bank Transfer (recommended)<br/>
                                <input type="radio" name="payment" value="PayPal" />PayPal (additional 3% commission)<br/>
                                <input type="radio" name="payment" value="Western Union" />Western Union<br/>
                                <input type="radio" name="payment" value="MoneyGram" />MoneyGram<br/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><div align="left">Link To Your Order</div></td>
                            <td><textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="orderLinks"  ></textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><div align="left">Size</div></td>
                            <td><input style="width:50px" type="text" size="25px" name="size"  /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><div align="left">Color</div></td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="25px" name="color"  /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><div align="left">Cost of Your Item</div></td>
                            <td><input style="width:50px" type="text" name="cost"  /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><div align="left">Order Agreement</div></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked="checked" value="check" /><a href="#" id="agreement">View Order Agreement</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Place Order!" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
</form>';
    echo $memberOrder;

    // Start assembly of Email Member the activation link
    $to = "yankeesmarket@gmail.com";
    // Change this to your site admin email
    $from = "$memberNumber";
    $subject = "Member Order Placed";
    //Begin HTML Email Message where you need to change the activation URL inside
    $message = '<html>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    Member Number:  '.$memberNumber.' <br/><br/>
    Payment Type:  '.$payment.' <br/><br/>
    Order Links:  '.$orderLinks.' <br/><br/>
    Size:  '.$size.' <br/><br/>
    Color: '.$color.' <br/><br/>
    Order Cost: '.$cost.' <br/><br/>
    </body>
    </html>';
    // end of message
    $headers = "From: $from\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $to = "$to";
    // Finally send the activation email to the member
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


}else{
```

Comment: can u show what the header would look like?

Comment: "didn't work" - what do you mean?

Comment: do you want to redirect after the Order! (submit)..?

Comment: Wait is order.php the same page as the code, or is that another page? Because if you are hitting "submit" it will take to order.php if you don't write a script to prevent that.

Comment: Eric, the header function would be in the if statement and after the person hits submit, it would take them to their account to see their order, so something like header ("member_account.php");
And at the bottom else statement, I want to redirect them to a thank you message using the print""; statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write anything to the browser and expect the `header` function to work. In order to set headers, the response body must be empty.

So I suggest to do something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // do the INSERT and whatnot
    // when finished call the header function
    header("Location: my_custom_page.php");
}
else{
    // output the form, javascript and what you need
}
```

So the first time the page loads, it will go in the `else` statement, because you have no POST data. This will print out the form and validation JavaScript. When the form gets submitted, the request lands in the `if`, and the order is placed, and then the client is redirected.

Again, in the `if` statement, you are not allowed to make any `echo`s. A very bad alternative to this, would be to echo a small javascript that does the redirect (I **don't** recommend this. ever):

```
<script>window.location.href = 'my_custom_page.php';</script>
```

Comment: or, wrap all the rendered elements in ob_start() ob_flush_end() (I think?)

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility too. I've used it when I was under 2 years of experience, but now I don't. I guess it has it's upsides and downsides, but generally I wouldn't recommend it in this case.

Comment: Eduard, I understand what you mean but my else statement right now outputs the form for non registered users.  I need it to be there.  When the page loads, either the if statement loads for registered users, or the else statement loads for non registered.  I was trying to write a header at the end of the if and at the end of the else after the forms were submitted, you know what I mean?

Comment: in that case, handle the post on a separate PHP page, then just redirect from there

Comment: Separate the `if` and `else`. Leave the code in the else (the form HTML code) in the original file, and move the email sending in a separate file, called `process_order.php` for example. Then you just have to change the `action` of your form to `process_order.php`. It would be good to have something like: `if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) echo "You can't access this page directly";` in the process page, so people can't access it by browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would construct the process:

1. Verify that the user is logged in
2. Validate the email fields (presence, formatting, etc)
3. Store the data in MySQL. If the insertion is successful, proceed to mailing?
4. Attempt to mail with the information. If successful, redirect using the [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.
5. If unsuccessful, proceed with outputting the page and any error messaging.

Remember that you cannot alter the page headers if even one character has been output or rendered to the page.

*ALSO,* you should choose to use another means of mail delivery as the `mail()` message will go to the Junk folder guaranteed, as it uses the server information in the sender headers.

Comment: What would be another mail function to send the data to myself?  I'm a beginner at this stuff so I'm just following tutorials and changing the data to my needs.  What other function would I use?  The test runs I made send the letter to my inbox...

Comment: I have had a lot of success with [PHPmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) which requires you to include your email credentials to use your SMTP servers.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use JS you can do anytime in the html:

```
<script>
  window.location.href = <?php echo $url; ?>
</script>
```

Comment: why exactly? when its to late for header redirection this is a simple solution.

Comment: Using JavaScript to implement site critical functionality is just a bad idea. It presupposes that JavaScript is enabled. You can make it better, but you'd have to supply a `<noscript>` solution in the case this does nothing. And to be honest, what's the graceful degrade to a non-functional `window.location.href` change?